# Implementing google charts in android application to generate report

Tags: android, google-visualization

Hi I have no idea how to make charts with the help of google api.
I have some value  in database according to date and I want to display as graph and charts in my application, For example:

Date      |  counter
20/9/2012    10
21/9/2012    2
24/9/2012    5
26/9/2012    1
30/9/2012    8

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a WebView and in that You can randor GOOGLE CHart api generated chart...

E.g

```
  String url =  "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=p3&chs=500x200&chd=e:TNTNTNGa&chts=000000,16&chtt=A+Better+Web&chl=Hello|Hi|anas|Explorer&chco=FF5533,237745,9011D3,335423&chdl=Apple|Mozilla|Google|Microsoft";
        WebView mCharView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.char_view);
        mCharView.loadUrl(url);
```

Add following in Manifest file...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

On top of that you can do simple charting as well if your charts are simple without using GOOGLE Chart API...